# Android: textView-set y-coordinate dynamically

Tags: android, set, textview, coordinates, dynamic

I tried using textview.setTranslationY(float) to change the y-coordinate of the textview but it does not seem to work. textview.setTop() seems to do the same function but the documentation says this method is meant to be called by the layout system and should not generally be called otherwise, because the property may be changed at any time by the layout.
I use textview.getTranslationY() to get the y-coordinate.

How can I set the y-coordinate of textview? If what I am doing above is wrong, kindly suggest an alternative way. Maybe there is another method to set y-coordinate which I have not found yet!

My situation: I have a textview whose height should change based on some value received. If I use textview.setHeight(int), the height increases from top to bottom. I want it to increase from bottom to top. So I change the y-coordinate of the textview every time I set it's height.

Cheers,

Madhu

Screen shot of my layout:

[image: My layout]

Comment: Look at the .setLayoutParams() method. One of the options in the LayoutParams object will let you change the position. But as the answers state it would be easier to just use alignparentbottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you change the height of the `TextView` only? You said...

> the height increases from top to bottom

So... in that case you can align the `TextView` at the bottom. For instance, if you are using `RelativeLayout` as the container of the `TextView`, you can use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.

Comment: I have an imageview and a textview each on top and bottom of this imageview. And to the left of this imageview is this textview whose height I want to vary. I am using an AbsoluteLayout. If I try RelativeLayout, I cannot place all these views in the positions I want. Can I align the textview in AbsoluteLayout as well?

Comment: Man, you shouldn't use `AbsoluteLayout`... it's deprecated. Could you please paste a screenshot of your layout... `RelativeLayout` is really powerful, and you can do almost everything you want.

Comment: I have added a screen shot my layout-AbsoluteLayout. The bar at the bottom has to be vertical instead of horizontal. Would be great if you can help me with this. Also, please tell me how to make this layout with RelativeLayout.

Comment: Thank you so much. I used RelativeLayout and the alignment you told me and it worked like a chram :-)

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought about using a `RelativeLayout` and use `align_parent_bottom`?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html